# FOR-loop does NOT work in Postgres 11.8 when using it in Pl/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, for-loop, plpgsql

I'm trying out examples for FOR loops from PostgreSQLTutorial website on this [link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-loop-statements/) and [this](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/) is sample database that's being used. Problem is I can not get to work is the following *for-loop* example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION for_loop_through_query(
   n INTEGER DEFAULT 10
) 
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT title 
           FROM film 
           ORDER BY title
           LIMIT n 
    LOOP 
    RAISE NOTICE '%', rec.title;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run `select for_loop_through_query(5);` I get no result at all!
I've tried running it in DataGrip as well as in pgAdmin4 and PostgreSQL version is **11.8** on **Fedora 30** OS. Also I've tried replacing n argument type with `int` instead of `INTEGER`. 
 Am I missing something (*command*/*additional setup*)? Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

**P.S.** On their [website](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/install-postgresql/) it's stated that PostgreSQL 11.3 has been installed, so I guess their examples have to be run on not so much older version of PostgreSQL than mine.

**UPDATE1:**
 
Excepted output should be:

> NOTICE:  Academy Dinosaur 
>   NOTICE:  Ace Goldfinger
>   NOTICE:  AdaptationHoles
>   NOTICE:  Affair Prejudice
>  
>   NOTICE:  African Egg

Output that I get:

```
postgres=# select * FROM version();
                                                version                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

... and when I perform 2 following commands
`sudo su - postgres` and
`psql dvdrental postgres` I get this output:

```
dvdrental=# select for_loop_through_query(5);
NOTICE:  Academy Dinosaur
NOTICE:  Ace Goldfinger
NOTICE:  Adaptation Holes
NOTICE:  Affair Prejudice
NOTICE:  African Egg
 for_loop_through_query 
------------------------

(1 row)
```

What seems to be problem then when invoking this function in DataGrip and pgAdmin4...any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PostgreSQL 11.8 it works if you have data in the table.

Note that your function returns `void` so you have no real result set: a function should return some data otherwise you could use a procedure.

```
select * from version();
                                                 version                        

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (R
ed Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit
(1 row)

select * from film;
 title 
-------
 ABC0
 ABC1
 ABC2
 ABC3
 ABC4
 ABC5
 ABC6
 ABC7
 ABC8
(9 rows)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION for_loop_through_query(
   n INTEGER DEFAULT 10
) 
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT title 
           FROM film 
           ORDER BY title
           LIMIT n 
    LOOP 
    RAISE NOTICE '%', rec.title;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

select * from for_loop_through_query(5);
NOTICE:  ABC0
NOTICE:  ABC1
NOTICE:  ABC2
NOTICE:  ABC3
NOTICE:  ABC4
 for_loop_through_query 
------------------------

(1 row)

select for_loop_through_query(5);
NOTICE:  ABC0
NOTICE:  ABC1
NOTICE:  ABC2
NOTICE:  ABC3
NOTICE:  ABC4
 for_loop_through_query 
------------------------

(1 row)
```

Because your function does not return any data you can get RAISE NOTICE messages in pgAdmin4 **only in the `Messages` tab**:

```
NOTICE:  ABC0
NOTICE:  ABC1
NOTICE:  ABC2
NOTICE:  ABC3
NOTICE:  ABC4
NOTICE:  ABC5
NOTICE:  ABC6
NOTICE:  ABC7
NOTICE:  ABC8

Successfully run. Total query runtime: 54 msec.
1 rows affected.
```

Comment: but I DO have data in table

Comment: Please post output you have with `psql` and detail what is your expected output: NOTICE messages ? function result ?

Comment: updated my question as you asked in your last comment, please take a look

Comment: To have `RAISE NOTICE` messages in client application you need to have an application able to retrieve this data from database side: pgAdmin knows how to do this but I cannot tell about Data Grid (`RAISE NOTICE` messages are **different** from data returned by usual DML like `SELECT` statement].

Comment: true, I've checked for similar 'Message' tab/option (like in pgAdmin4) in DataGrip and it does have it in a form of 'Output' console...obviously I've overseen it while it was showing me additional tab for ResultSet. Thank you once again. :)